# How to use this for loop to get expected result in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
a=['hi','helllo']
for i in a:
    for j in i:
         print j
```

I'm getting output as :
    h
    i
    h
    e
    l
    l
    o

What i'm expecting is 
    hi
    hello

Is there anyway to do achieve this ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry for not saying clearly.. i want the same output via 2 for loops as mentioned.. thats the problem.. anyway we can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

As you insist on using nested for loops, here a way to make that work:

```
import sys

a = ['hi','helllo']
first = True
for i in a:
    if not first:
        sys.stdout.write(' ')
    first = False
    for j in i:
         sys.stdout.write(j)
print()
```

This writes each character directly to `sys.stdout`. It ensures that a space character separates each word, and jumps through some hoops to make sure that there is no trailing space character. It's awful and I can not think of a reason to do it this way.

Here is a much better way to achieve it; use [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
>>> a = ['hi','helllo']
>>> print(' '.join(a))
hi helllo
```

The problem with the way that you are doing it is that the inner for loop iterates over each character contained in the strings in `a`, printing each on its own line. You could ditch the inner loop and print each string without a new line:

```
a = ['hi','helllo']
for i in a:
    print i,
```

The trailing comma on the `print` statement prevents a new line being printed. N.B. this is a Python 2 only solution. The `str.join()` method will work in both Python 2 and 3.

In Python 3 you can simply do this:

```
print(*a)
```

... and the same code can be made to work in Python 2 if you enable the `print()` *function* by adding to the top of your python file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: in the above mentioned example in the question, what i m getting is h is processed in second for loop and then 'i' is processsed.. i want first 'hi' to get processed in the second for loop...   any clue? @mhawke